# tkinter live data label changes (dependent on user input)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I'm trying to code a sorta medieval RPG, and I'm using Tkinter to display the user's health, stamina, controls, etc. I'm trying to make it so the user has a base stamina of 50 and if they press the "Attack" button, the stamina will decrease by 5 and slowly regenerate over time, (if the current STM is lower than 50 it starts adding by 1 point every millisecond until it reaches 50 again). I got the subtraction working for each time "Attack" is pressed, but I can't seem to get my `if (stamina < stmmax):` statement working at all. Any tips?

```
import time
import sys
import random as rand
from tkinter import *

# -----------------------------------Custom Functions---------------------------------------

def dramaticeffect():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("")

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("")

def die():
    delay_print("Your adventure has ended, " + name + ".")
    sys.exit()

def endprogress():
    print("[This is the end of the game's current progress]")
    die()

def actionlog():
    global log
    log = log + 1
    action = True
    print("\t inputlog#" + str(log))
    logcheck.configure(text="*")

def attack():
    global stamina
    stamina = int(stamina - 5)
    print(stamina)
    stmcount = ("Stamina: " + str(stamina) + "/" + str(stmmax))
    stmmeter.configure(text=stmcount)
    live = True
    actionlog()

'''
def uistart():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Fate of all")
    uidefault()

def uidefault():
    label = Label(window, text="Testing")
    entry = Entry(window)
    button1 = Button(window, text="Enter")
    button2 = Button(window, text="SB_1")
    button3 = Button(window, text="SB_2")

def uihalt():
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()
    button3.pack()

    window.mainloop()
'''

# ---------------------------------------Gameplay-------------------------------------------

window = Tk()
window.title("Fate of all")

log = int(0)

live = False

stmmod = int(0)
stamina = int(50 + stmmod)
stmmax = int(50 + stmmod)

if (stamina < stmmax):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    stamina = stamina + 1
    print(stamina)

stmcount = ("Stamina: " + str(stamina) + "/" + str(stmmax))

#damage

stmmeter = Label(window, text=stmcount)
entry = Entry(window)
button1 = Button(window, text="Enter", command=actionlog)
button2 = Button(window, text="Attack", command=attack)
button3 = Button(window, text="Defend", command=actionlog)
logcheck = Label(window, text="")

stmmeter.pack()
entry.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()
logcheck.pack()

window.mainloop()



#name = input("This is the tale of... ")

#dramaticeffect()

#delay_print('''
#Greetings, Sir ''' + name + ''', I am a humble traveler like you. Allow me to tell you a
#story, a tale of a friend or two.
#''')

#delay_print('''
#\t It is a desolate time, there are wars between sword and stone all
#across the land...and you were but a simple knight trying to survive,
#but everything changed once you entered the outer lands of Newlochia.
#''')

#delay_print("Fate of all is in your hands.")

#dramaticeffect()
```

Comment: You should do the recover task (add `stamina` by 1) inside a function and then use `after()` to call it periodically.  However recover `stamina` in every millisecond is a bit too fast, stamina will be back to 50 after 50 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all when you have an if statement in a Tk instance obviously it is going to run just once and secondly, it is not a good idea to use `time.sleep(some_num)` with GUI applications so it's better to use `root.after(millis, func)` and use it in a function.
It also depends when and where do you want to run your function. If you want it to just run when the character is attacked then you can do something like this and bind it to the button or call it in the other function that is already bound to your button:

```
def regenerate():
    global stamina
    if stamina < stmmax:
        stamina += 1
        root.after(60, regenerate)
        # root.after works with millis so it is better to use
        # a bigger number like 60 rather than 1
```

**UPDATE:** I tried implementing your code and I believe that this is more likely what you would want:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Game!")
root.geometry("400x300")
stamina, stmmax = 50, 50
regenerating = False
lbl = Label(root, text=f"Stamina: {stamina}")
lbl.pack(pady=15)


def regenerate():
    global regenerating
    if not regenerating:
        regenerating = True

        def add_stamina():
            global stamina, regenerating
            if stamina < stmmax:
                stamina += 1
                lbl.config(text=f"Stamina: {stamina}")
                root.after(100, add_stamina)
            else:
                regenerating = False

        add_stamina()

def attack():
    global stamina
    stamina -= 15
    lbl.config(text=f"Stamina: {stamina}")
    regenerate()

Button(root, text="Attack!", command=attack).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I also tried writing the function with a `while True: (smth)` loop and making use of `threading.Thread` to constantly check if the current stamina is less then the max stamina but it seems like in every trial the code failed and the GUI froze. Though just using normal functions is the better way.

**UPDATE:** Sorry for the many updates. thinking about the code I was unsatisfied that it was not really clean so I made a better version for **optimization** sake. Also in this situation where you are configuring the label a lot I rather set a **textvariable** for the label.
Code without textvariable:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Game!")
root.geometry("400x300")
stamina, stmmax = 50, 50
regenerating = False
lbl = Label(root, text=f"Stamina: {stamina}")
lbl.pack(pady=15)

def add_stamina():
    global stamina, regenerating
    if stamina < stmmax:
        stamina += 1
        lbl.config(text=f"Stamina: {stamina}")
        root.after(100, add_stamina)
    else:
        regenerating = False

def attack():
    global stamina, regenerating
    stamina -= 15
    lbl.config(text=f"Stamina: {stamina}")
    if not regenerating:
        regenerating = True
        add_stamina()

Button(root, text="Attack!", command=attack).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Same code with the textvariable:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Game!")
root.geometry("400x300")
stamina, stmmax = 50, 50
regenerating = False
stm_var = StringVar()
stm_var.set(f"Stamina: {stamina}")
lbl = Label(root, textvariable=stm_var)
lbl.pack(pady=15)

def add_stamina():
    global stamina, regenerating
    if stamina < stmmax:
        stamina += 1
        stm_var.set(f"Stamina: {stamina}")
        root.after(100, add_stamina)
    else:
        regenerating = False

def attack():
    global stamina, regenerating
    stamina -= 15
    stm_var.set(f"Stamina: {stamina}")
    if not regenerating:
        regenerating = True
        add_stamina()

Button(root, text="Attack!", command=attack).pack()
root.mainloop()
```